# IEで動作する、プルダウンで選択されている値のテキストを取得する方法

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

現在以下の実装になっており

```html
document.getElementsByName(name)[0].selectedOptions[0].textContent;
```

chromeはこれで動作しますが、IEでは動作しません。IEではselectedOptionsが使えないみたいです。
IEで動作するソースがしりたいのですが、方法の分かる方がいましたら、ご教授お願いします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

以下で取得出来ます

```html
var s = document.getElementById(id);
var item1 = s.options[s.selectedIndex].**text**;
```